# How do I get Python to see librt?

Tags: python, perforce, librt

I just installed python-dev with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

so that I can start using P4Python. But when I try to import P4, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-2.5/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 113, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "/opt/pycharm-2.5/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 44, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/home/nyap/proj/p4-rollback/Tools/Perforce/util/p4_rollback_unit_test.py", line 32, in <module>
    import P4
  File "/home/nyap/proj/p4-rollback/Tools/Perforce/p4python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/P4.py", line 312, in <module>
    import P4API
ImportError: /home/nyap/proj/p4-rollback/Tools/Perforce/p4python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/P4API.so: undefined symbol: clock_gettime
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few things to try.

- Are you certain that `librt.so` is available on your system?
- You can try running `ldd` on `/home/nyap/proj/p4-rollback/Tools/Perforce/p4python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/P4API.so` to see what shared libraries it wants to link against.  Is `librt` listed?  Is it found?
- You can try preloading `librt` and see if that helps:

  ```
  LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/librt.so python ...
  ```
- You can enable debugging in the dynamic loader by setting `LD_DEBUG=libs`:

  ```
  LD_PRELOAD=libs python
  ```

  This will display information about what libraries the loader is looking for and where it finds them.

Hopefully one of these things will help out.